# Android how to do sliding diagonal affect using drag

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

am trying to do diagonal dragging using xamarin android (non xamarin will also help )

i want the user to be able to drag the green part(see image) using his finger , while dragging it need to be diagonal (it starts at the beginning like the red part )
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtHDw.jpg)

i gut the sliding part so far , but i have no idea how to do the diagonal sliding part

```
    private float _viewX;
    private int _originalLeft;
    private int _originalRight;
    private View _greenView;
    private View _redView;



    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.QuestionsView);

        _greenView = FindViewById<View>(Resource.Id.greenTrueView);
        _redView = FindViewById<View>(Resource.Id.redFalseView);

        _greenView.SetOnTouchListener(this);
        _redView.SetOnTouchListener(this);

    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (v.Equals(_greenView))
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {

                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    _viewX = e.GetX();
                    _originalLeft = v.Left;
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    var left = (int)(e.RawX - _viewX);
                    v.Layout(left, v.Top, v.Right, v.Bottom);
                    break;


            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    _viewX = e.GetX();
                    _originalRight = v.Right;
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    var right = (int)(_viewX + e.RawX);
                    v.Layout(v.Left, v.Top, right, v.Bottom);
                    break;


            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please post some codes to show what you have tried so far?

Comment: hi @ElvisXia-MSFT, edited with the current code i have

Answer (score 0):

> i gut the sliding part so far , but i have no idea how to do the diagonal sliding part

Diagonal sliding means by every sliding, vertical offset has a fixed ratio to its horizontal offset. For example: a 45 degree Diagonal sliding: vertical offset= 1*(horizontal offset). So, what you need to do is just to modify vertical offset according to `_viewX`:

```
private View green_view,red_view;
private float _viewX;
private float _viewY;
private int _originalLeft,_originalRight;

if(v.Equals(green_view))
    {
        switch (event.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                _viewX=event.GetX();
                _viewY=event.GetY();
                _originalLeft=v.Left;
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                int left=(int)(event.RawX()-_viewX);
                //if the fixed ratio is 1, you can set it by any number like 1/2
                int top=left;
                v.Layout(left,top,v.Right,v.Bottom);
                break;
        }
 ...
```

Comment: thanks for the help , did you see the image i posted in the question of what sliding am trying to achieve? in your solution your just changing the top layout point , meaning when i drag it then it will start from the bottom corner and go up .

Comment: Please expand your `View` to let it be big enough to cover the whole screen.

Comment: not sure what do you mean , when we start the activity , the green view height takes all available space  (the starting  width in my case is 30dp) if i use your code and change the top as you did its the view height is changed and its not taking all the height any more

Comment: I mean, makes your green view bigger enough so that after sliding, it can take up the whole screen.